# How can i send Limited records in join i in below i want to send limited records of survey_result table t4?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
FROM survey_result t4 
JOIN questionnaire_survey_result t1 ON t4.user_id = 11 and t4.survey_id = 1
JOIN question_categories t3 ON t2.category_id = t3.id
GROUP BY t3.category_name
```

As I am getting result from all Records from Survey Result I want to get Limited of 20 for eg

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: You can use row_number() function to limit the number of records. Do you want to filter based on specific condition ?